# How does variable scoping work with python imports

Tags: python, import

I am having difficulty understanding how global variables from a module are actually imported in another module. Suppose we have a module mod1.py coded as below:

```
#mod1.py
var1 = None
def test():
    global var1
    var1=1
```

---

and, another module mod2.py that intends to use mod1.py, as below:

---

```
#mod2.py
from mod1 import *  #This may not be a good coding practice, but it's relevant to my question
print "var1="+str(var1)
test()
print "var1="+str(var1)
```

---

When executing mod2, the print statements print:

```
var1=None
var1=None
```

---

which means that the value of var1 that was imported as a result of "from mod1 import *" did not bear any change in mod2 by calling test(). On the other hand, if I code mod2 as below:

---

```
#mod2.py
import mod1
print "var1="+str(mod1.var1)
mod1.test()
print "var1="+str(mod1.var1)
```

---

The first and second print statements print:

```
var1=None
var1=1
```

---

which means that the value of var1 was changed by a call to mod1.test().

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common analogy for this is to think of strings tied to balloons.  Think of every assignment statement as tying a string to a balloon.  e.g.

```
a = 1  # tie a string "a" to the `1` balloon
b = a  # tie a string to the same balloon that "a" is tied to.
```

Assigning a new thing to an existing variable is akin to cutting the current string and tying it to something else:

```
a = 2  # cut string tying "a" to 1 and tie it to the `2` balloon
```

In the first version (`from mod1 import *`) you basically do a whole bunch of assignment statements:

```
var1 = mod1.var1
...
```

Now, you have 2 strings tied to the 1 balloon -- `mod1.var1` and `mod2.var1`.  After you call the `test` function, you cut the string of `mod1.var1` and tie it to the "2" balloon.

In the second example (`import mod1`), you have a string (`mod2.mod1`) tied to the `mod1` *module*, but no explicit string tied to `mod1.var1`.  So now when you re-tie the `mod1.var1` string, you can still look it up the same way -- The string tied to `mod1` hasn't change, only the string from `mod1` to `mod1.var1`.

Comment: To add to the answer, try changing up mod2 a bit.  Have it `from mod1 import *` and then do `test()`.  Then add a line to `import mod1`, followed by `print mod1.var1`.  You'll see that `mod1.var1` reflects the new value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys. With "from mod1 import *", if after calling test(), I do "from mod1 import *" again, var1 in mod2 gets set to the updated value of mod1.var1 which is 1 (not None). This all makes sense to me.